# Debug Android Analytics event tracking - Analytics not picking up events

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've successfully added Analytics to an Android app and it is picking up session data just fine. However, I've also tried to track a specific event, but it does not seem to be sent to Analytics like the rest of the session data. I've followed the code suggested in the current Analytics documentation and still no luck, so I'm pasting here in the hopes that it's something obvious to more experienced folks. Many thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_import);
    user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
    statusUpdateArea = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dataStatusUpdateField);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    welcomeMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WelcomeMessageTextView);
    welcomeMessage.append(user);
    // getting tracker & setting User ID field
    AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker.set("&uid", user);
    // build and send event
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("User ID")
            .setAction("Data login")
            .setLabel(user)
            .build());
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need use

```
mTracker = application.getTracker();
```

and

```
mTracker.setScreenName("yourscreenname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are calling send before calling build .
Create a tracker with all the event info then call build and once done call send function .

Have worked on webtrends analytics product so I know a thing or two about analytics

Comment: Ideally it should be mtracker.build.setcategory(Id).setaction(action).setlabel(label).send